# MessageBox error System.EventArgs does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a `MessageBoxButtons.YesNo`and I know you can make a dialog for `formclosing` but I wanted to make this for one of my EXIT buttons. I am getting this error where I declared `e.Canel = true` in Button3

Here's my code:

```cs
using LOGINPAGE.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LOGINPAGE
{
    public partial class FACULTY : Form
    {
        public FACULTY()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SetFloorsToDropDown();
        }

        private void FACULTY_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'roomInfoDataSet2.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tableTableAdapter1.Fill(this.roomInfoDataSet2.Table);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'roomInfoDataSet1.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.roomInfoDataSet1.Table);


        }

        private void xButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Floor.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }

        private void xButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.Close();
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void xButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else  
            {

                e.Cancel = true;
            }

        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void xButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Floor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            if (Floor.SelectedItem.ToString() != "SELECT FLOOR")
            {
                foreach (var item in roomInfoDataSet1.Table.Where(x => x.Room_Number.Substring(0, 1) == Convert.ToString(Floor.SelectedValue)))
                {
                    string[] row = new string[] { item.Room_Number, Convert.ToString(Floor.SelectedValue) };

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;
                    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
                }
            }
        }

        private void SetFloorsToDropDown()
        {
            List<DropDownModel> floorList = new List<DropDownModel>();

            floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
            {
                Id = 0,
                Name = "SELECT FLOOR",
            });

            floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "1st Floor",
            });

            floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "2nd Floor",
            });

            floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "3rd Floor",
            });

            floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
            {
                Id = 4,
                Name = "4th Floor",
            });

            floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
            {
                Id = 5,
                Name = "5th Floor",
            });

            floorList.Add(new DropDownModel()
            {
                Id = 6,
                Name = "6th Floor",
            });

            Floor.DataSource = floorList;
            Floor.DisplayMember = "Name";
            Floor.ValueMember = "Id";
        }



        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void xButton1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: You're using a button. There's no Cancel property. Just drop the `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I understood the problem is in `xButton3_Click()`. Change it to:

```
private void xButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

You do not need to use `else`. Just leave it as is. If user choose 'Yes' then application will close, in other way no action is needed

Comment: Yep, I got it working! Now, is there a way to do this with opening different windows? I'm guessing it would be the same? Like if if the message box say like **do you want to open this window?** and they hit yes or no

Comment: I would suggest updating your answer's code to show him what he **should** be doing.

Comment: Never mind! Haha I just basically gave the same the `if` statement with `this.hide();` and  'this.Show();` for the `yes` and an `else` statement for the `no` thanks megatron~